# R - Como substituir "." (ponto) por " " (espaço) no nome das colunas de um Data.Table?

Tags: r, data.rable-r

Tenho um data.table extenso, com 64 colunas.

Os nomes das colunas estão separados por pontos e eu gostaria de separar por espaço.

Exemplo:

> Atual: "Salário.Janeiro", "Salário.Dezembro", "Salário.Médio"
>
> Eu quero: "Salário Janeiro", "Salário Dezembro", "Salário Médio"

Sei que a função names() altera o nome das colunas e o gsub() faz a substituição dos caracteres. Entretanto, não estou sabendo como aplicar isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deu certo utilizando:

```
names(df) <- gsub(pattern, replace, names(df))
```

No meu caso:

```
names(df) <- gsub("\\.", " ", names(df))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Exemplo 1**
O primeiro exemplo mostra como alterar os nomes das colunas em um quadro de dados. Isso começa com a primeira coluna e vai até os nomes que você forneceu. Por exemplo, se houver oito colunas em seu quadro de dados, mas você fornecer apenas dois nomes, apenas as duas primeiras colunas serão renomeadas.

```
names(data) <- c("new_name", "another_new_name")
```

**Exemplo 2** O segundo exemplo mostra como alterar o nome de uma coluna usando o nome para identificar a qual coluna aplicar o nome. O código a seguir renomeará o campo old_name para new_name no quadro de dados chamado data.

```
# Rename a column in R
colnames(data)[colnames(data)=="old_name"] <- "new_name"
```

Se você sabe a quantidade de colunas (quant_col) poderá iterar e alterar o nome das colunas dinamicamente da seguinte forma:

```
for(i in 1:quant_col) {
  names(data)[i]<-"new_name"
}
```

Comment: Sim, mas nesse caso eu teria que fazer coluna por coluna. Não teria uma função para substituir tudo de uma vez ?

Comment: @RicardoTheodoro

Answer (score 1):

É só usar `gsub` com a expressão regular seguinte: `"\\."`. Como o ponto `"."` é um metacaráter, tem que se usar a sequência de escape com as duas contra barras.

```
nomes <- c("Salário.Janeiro", "Salário.Dezembro", "Salário.Médio")

nomes <- gsub("\\.", " ", nomes)
nomes
#[1] "Salário Janeiro"  "Salário Dezembro" "Salário Médio"
```

**No entanto** eu não recomendo que faça isso, não costuma ser boa ideia ter espaços nos nomes de colunas. Não há nada a ganhar (que eu saiba) e pode dar problemas.

Comment: Obrigado ! É quase isso que eu queria. Mas consegui resolver, estava esquecendo o "\\."  e usando apenas "." ! Valeu.

Comment: Sobre a recomendação, eu entendo. Mas é que esse é o formato da RAIS, então optei por manter.

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção usando o pacote stringr

```
str_replace(nomes,
            pattern = "\\.",
            replacement = " ")

[1] "Salário Janeiro"  "Salário Dezembro" "Salário Médio"
```